# Delete a file from git history only after a certain commit

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

There are tools, such as git filter-repo, to delete a file from the whole git history, as if it never existed.

Is it possible to delete a file from the git history, but only after a certain commit? Let's say I want to keep the initial 100 versions of the file, but from version 101-200 I want it deleted from the repo.

Comment: The older `git filter-branch` can take a range of commits as argument, so you can go with `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached that/file' <commit100>..master` and only commits 101-200 will be rewritten.

Comment: `git filter-repo` has a `--refs` option which technically could accept a range of commits, however I know that `git filter-repo` relies on `git fast-export / fast-import`, and I am not sure about the end result of `git filter-repo` in that case. You may try it on a fresh clone of your own repository.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above by @legec, the syntax using git-filter-repo to delete a file after a certain commit is:

```
git-filter-repo --path "path/to/file" --invert-paths --refs c`3c1a385123eb3bf978de3bee99d2101ea26521a..HEAD
```

(replace c3c1a385123eb3bf978de3bee99d2101ea26521a with the initial commit you want to keep, so if you want to delete a file from a certain folder you have to choose one commit before that one)

And the simpler syntax to delete a file from the whole history:

```
git-filter-repo --replace-refs delete-no-add --path "path/to/file" --invert-paths
```

Replace --path with --path-glob if you want to use wildcards

```
git-filter-repo --replace-refs delete-no-add --path-glob "path/to/fi*" --invert-paths
```

**Disclaimer**: this is a dangerous operation that can easily delete mess up your repository. E.g. forgetting "--invert-paths" in one operation will delete everything and keep just the file you wanted to delete. It will also complicate things if other users have active branches, etc.